# Do we need to use ssms if visual studio already has sql server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, visual-studio-2019

Just like the title, why do we need to use ssms if visual studio (2019) already has sql server?

I am just starting to EXLPORE MORE about databases (.mdf) in c# (specifically for standalone desktop apps) and try to make them secure, as I am doing my searches I stumbled upon SSMS. I don't even know if SSMS is "necessary" since I can just create a service-based database and do the queries there. I have also deployed a desktop app to client machine with just service-based (.mdf) database (without ssms).

As you can see in this image, I'll just go to Server Explorer and then I can just do database stuff right? create tables, stored procedure, functions, etc.

[image]

I can also go to SQL Server Object Explorer to do some database stuff that ssms can do. Like logins, server roles etc.

[image]

Can someone please enlighten me about the importance of using ssms? or why do we even need it?

If I watch youtube tutorials about CRUD, most of them is using ssms, and I don't, I just add a service-based database and it just works.

**Edit:**
Thank you for everyone who commented and even answered in my post, but I have found [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/writing-sql-in-ssms-vs-microsoft-visual-studio) helpful website that really enlightened me about the difference of ssms and vs(for sql).

Based on Grant Fritchey's Answer:

> As to point four, are you developing code and databases? You may see better use in VS (source control being the biggie here). Are you managing servers and databases as well as developing code and databases? You may see better use in SSMS.

For now, I'm just going to stick with VS since it all fits my needs and I am still not managing servers like a system admin.

Comment: Ssms has plenty of tools for backup, security, db management.... that are out of scope for a dev, and therefore are absent from VS

Comment: Visual Studio and SSMS serve different purposes. Which you use depends on your use case. And by that i mean "use at the time" not which you install. Many have both installed as, again, they use them for different tasks. Personally, I tend to use ADS for Database Projects, but that's because I work on Linux a lot too, so working in the same IDE makes things easier.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I edited my post, I can just go to SQL Server Object Explorer and just do some stuff that ssms can right?

Comment: @Larnu I don't mind just using vs only, I just don't know the advantages of ssms, since I can do thoses things (in the post) in vs alone.

Comment: @Hacki - try e.g. viewing the SQL Server logs. They aren't exposed in SQL Server Object Explorer. If you don't need those currently, then go ahead and just use Object Explorer, but as others have tried to tell you, they surface different tools, so don't just dismiss one as redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing that you can do within SQL Server can be done through code. Yeah, you'll need at least two languages, one to manage the OS & SQL Server service, and the other, T-SQL, to manage all the rest. However, no GUI of any kind is needed. Everything can be done through the code.

With that in mind, which code editing software do you like? Visual Studio? Awesome. Go write code.

Now, fact is, not all of us can memorize every single bit of T-SQL needed to manage a system from soup to nuts. So, we use a GUI to make things easier. The VS GUI does some things to assist writing CRUD statements, creating some structures, stuff around the management of the internals of a single database. The SSMS GUI on the other hand, does all that, then a ton more, focused on servers, instances, databases, and pretty much everything necessary to manage SQL Server. It has tools built in to help you set up Availability Groups, consume Extended Event data, manage security, backup databases, restore databases and more. None of this is available through VS.

So, the GUI is just a tool.

Do you need a philips head screw driver? There you go, Visual Studio. Do you need a scientifically calibrated impact wrench? There you go, SQL Server Management Studio. These things are just tools. Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio and SSMS are separate products and have specific areas that they are good at. VS is more designed to make development easier. Yes you can definitely connect to SQL via VS but the functionalities that you can do are somewhat limited. SSMS provides a much better toolset if you will be doing some stuffs with SQL Server. This is actually something that will depend on the user, for me I use VS to do development stuffs and SSMS to do SQL stuffs. Just my 2 cents. Hope this answer could help.

Comment: What do you mean by limited? Can you give me any links that I can refer to? I really want to learn more about databases. Like my post, I can just do those ssms stuff in just VS2019